# What is the difference between (+) and (-) operator in obj c function

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Hi i am new to iphone and starts to learning Obj c.

i have notice the function definition, for some function we are using (-) and for some function we are using (+)

Example:
+ (id)requestWithURL:(NSURL *)theURL

– initWithURL:

what the difference between those two operator / symbol's usage?

thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**In the context of a class definition, `+/-` determine whether the methods are instance or class level methods.**

`+` indicates the method is class level, and you don't need an instance to call it.

`-` indicates the method is an instance method, and must be called through an instance of an object.

A common example of a static (+) method is `NSString::stringWithFormat`, when you call it, you do so without an instance, but rather using the class name:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat: @"Your age is %d", age];
```

An instance method must be called on an instance of an appropriate object, an example of one would be:

```
NSString *s = @"oop:ack:zonks::ponies";
int len = [s length]; // instance method called
```

These symbols should not be confused with the mathematical operators `+` and `-`, which can only be applied as part of binary or unary arithmetic expressions.

Answer (score 3):

`+` = Static methods (i.e. you don't need an instance of the class to call the method - but you can't use non-static member variables or anything like that)

`-` = Instance methods